# Does Sublime Text have FTP Capabilities (Out-of-the-Box)

Tags: ftp, sublimetext

I am evaluating Sublime Text. I just installed it and cannot locate a way to setup an FTP connection to my server.

So I began to Google this issue and I see a variety of FTP software that I might use.

But my basic question is (more of a confirmation I guess) "does Sublime Text come with FTP capabilities out-of-the-box or do you, in fact, need to install an FTP plug-in?

And if you need a 3PTY FTP Plug-in, is there one that is a best fit for Sublime Text?

Thanks.

P.S. searched the Sublime Text site and there is no mention of FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a plugin to do it. I believe [SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) is pretty popular. You may also want to search for FTP on the package control [page](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/ftp). Though packages don't have to be on package control, many (likely most) are.